# change folder name in url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I want change the folder name on fly, using htaccess

this is actual url : http://dailycode.local:8384/home/View/dashboard/

I want to see this url like this : http://dailycode.local:8384/en/v/dashboard/

change the : 
"home" -> en
"view" -> v

Answer (score 0):

To 301 redirect all files in the direct to the new directory in .htaccess, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old\ foldr/(.*) /newfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

This should redirect all HTML pages, images, you name it.  It should also account for the space too.

You'll want to move all your files to the new folder location so when the redirect happens your end user doesn't receive a 404 error.

Also, you might possibly have to detail the white-space explicitly with '\s'

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old\sfoldr/(.*) /newfolder/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I don't want redirection, i want just change folder name in url thats it.
there are no folder exists like "en" and "v", just change the name from home to en and View to v

Comment: yes and my code will still work but slightly different. If you want a great guide check this out: [guide for you](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)